# How to query the history record of when the USB driver which has been used?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, usb, hardware, external-disk

I always use one USB flash disk on my MacBook Air (OS X 10.10.3), but I lost it recently. I need a way to view when the last date & time the USB device was connected to the computer.

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you problem you are facing

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to find the time record in system which the USB flash disk was pulled in/out.

Comment: What OSX version do you have

Comment: Did my answer work?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately peripheral connections are simply something that isn't logged by your Mac. Just think - why would it need to keep a written log of when a USB drive is plugged in?

Hope you end up finding it again!

Answer (score 0):

Apple's USB Prober *should* do the trick